# ShortestPath with 3 or more nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to execute a Cypher Query with Neo4J.
I already execute a Shortest path beetween 2 nodes, but I'm want to know if is possible to execute with more nodes.

Ex with 2 nodes:

```
MATCH (personA:Person { contactId: 1000073595058 }),(personB:Person { contactId: 1000295524418 }), p = shortestPath((personA)-[*..30]-(personB)) RETURN p
```

Ex with 3 nodes:

```
MATCH (personA:Person { contactId: 1000073595058 }),(personB:Person { contactId: 1000295524418 }),(personC:Person { contactId: 1000331998948 }), p = shortestPath((personA)-[*..30]-(personB)-[*..30]-(personC)) RETURN p
```

But when I execute returns a exception. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you please add the exception raised?

Comment: shortestPath(...) requires a pattern containing a single relationship (line 1, column 150 (offset: 149))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only `MATCH` a `shotestPath` between two nodes. You have to split up your query:

```
MATCH (personA:Person { contactId: 1000073595058 }),
      (personB:Person { contactId: 1000295524418 }),
      (personC:Person { contactId: 1000331998948 })
WITH personA, personB, personC
MATCH p = shortestPath((personA)-[..30]-(personB)
MATCH p2 = shortestPath((personB)-[..30]-(personC)
RETURN p, p2
```

Depending on what you want to do with the results, you can use aggregation functions to e.g. get all nodes from both paths:

```
...
RETURN nodes(p)+nodes(p2)
```

Comment: This query worked!

MATCH (personA:Person { contactId: 1000073595058 }),
      (personB:Person { contactId: 1000295524418 }),
      (personC:Person { contactId: 1000331998948 })
WITH personA, personB, personC
MATCH p = shortestPath((personA)-[*..30]-(personB)
MATCH p2 = shortestPath((personB)-[*..30]-(personC)
RETURN p, p2